# Typhoon DI occurs EXC_BAD_ACCES

Tags: swift, dependencies, code-injection, exc-bad-access, typhoon

I use Typhoon library to do dependency injection. I want to inject my navigator, but i get below error

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff89e06698)"

What can i do? Thanks!

My Assembly class:

```
public class CoreAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func navigator() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(Navigatior.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition?.key = "NAVIGATOR"
            definition?.scope = .lazySingleton
            } as AnyObject
    }
}
```

My appdelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let assembly = CoreAssembly().activated()
        let navigator = assembly.navigator() as! IITNavigation // and here is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

        navigator.loadRootScreen("")
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full logs. Also why do you cast to `IITNavigator` when the declared type is `Navigator`. Could you post the source to those files as well?